# How do you initialize uvm_mem?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Suppose I have an input file (`someinputdata.txt`) to be loaded in the uvm-based memory which is
declared as follows and instantiated somewhere on a register block (a class that extends
a `uvm_reg_block`).

```
class mymemory extends uvm_mem;
   `uvm_object_utils(mymemory)

   function new(string name = "mymemory");
      super.new(name, 32'h800, 32, "RW", UVM_NO_COVERAGE);
   endfunction

endclass
```

I'm not sure if there is a built-in function to load an input
file to `uvm_mem`.

How do you efficiently load `someinputdata.txt` to this memory?

Answer (score 2):

The `uvm_mem` class does not have a mirror of the actual memory. You will have to load it via a *front-door* or *back-door* method that you need to define. Back-door is preferred, so you need to define a user-defined backdoor access by extending the `uvm_reg_backdoor` class and implementing the `write()` method to write to the memory model as required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know some reference code somewhere on the net?

Comment: Sorry, I don't, and I can't seem to find anything. I think most people initialize their DUT memories outside of the UVM.